# How to generate adidional fields inside Yii form

Tags: yii

I have:

Table "user"
id, username, password

Table "freedate"
id, user_id, start_date, end_date

Each user can have 1 or more (unlimited) number of "freedate" entries.
Now i have form with 2 text fields (username and password), and 2 date pickers (one for start date and another one for end date).
How can i enable user to inserd aditional datepicker pairs so they can enter as much of "freedate" entires as they need to?
I was wondering about insertind aditional button inside form, that would somehow create aditional fields when pressed, but u have no idea how to do it.

I don't need working example (even tho one would help ofc). What i need i suggestion from your own expirience if you had similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript as noted above.  Though that can get tricky to get the new fields associated with the datepicker.

You can also submit after each pair is entered.  On returning back to form after save insert a new set of start/end date fields to the end of the form.  This way they always have a freedate pair they can enter.  (a bit slower overall)

Comment: At the end i did just this. User enters first pair and presses "save" which reloads form with list of pairs he already entered and fields for new pair. Works like a charm. For no i'll let it stay this way and in the future ill try to create "ajax" version which would let user insert new fields w/o submiting form.

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript to generate these fields on the fly. Or a fixed amount of extra fields could be hidden and shown one by one using javascript as the user clicks the button. You would need to keep track of the number of fields being shown in a javascript var.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom javascript in order to do that. It isn't hard, you would need to do something along these lines:

You need to create a button and, when that button gets clicked (`onClick` event or jquery `click()` function) you can add the html for your field (`<input type=.... />` and so on to your form) and remember to use the correct name for these fields so that they get sent correctly when the user submits the form.